# Adding multiple IF formulas into one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the four formulas below that I need compiled into one cell block. Please help!

```
=IF(SOURCE!C24>=90,"A"," ")
=IF(AND(SOURCE!C24>=80,SOURCE!C24<90),"B"," ")
=IF(AND(SOURCE!C24>=70,SOURCE!C24<80),"C"," ")
=IF(SOURCE!C24<70,"F"," ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
=IF(C1>=90, "A", IF(C1>=80,"B", IF(C1>=70, "C", IF(C1>=60, "D", "F"))))
```

You may need to add the worksheet references back in if you need them. To do that just change all references to `C1` to `SOURCE!C24`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `LOOKUP` function in this scenario - try this:

`=LOOKUP(Source!C24,{0,70,80,90},{"F","C","B","A"})`

The score is looked up against the "lower bounds" of each range in the first array and the relevant letter is returned from the second

Comment: The `LOOKUP` function is provided in Excel 2007 and later for backwards compatibility only.  I don't know when Microsoft will remove the formula.  Here is a different formula accomplishing the same thing: `=IF(Source!C24>=70,CHOOSE((C24-60)/10,"C","B","A"),"F")`

Comment: I'd be very surprised if MS removed **any** functions from Excel - I can't remember that happening in the last 15 years!.....but it's easily achievable with a similar syntax using other functions, e.g. `HLOOKUP` like this: `=HLOOKUP(Source!C24,{0,70,80,90;"F","C","B","A"},2)`