# Adding 2 formulas in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I add these 2 formulas together?

```
=IF(OR(AND(G14="No"), AND(G25="No")), "F")
```

If this formula does not result in "F", then

```
=IF(SOURCE!C24>=90,"A",IF(SOURCE!C24>=80,"B",IF(SOURCE!C24>=70,"C",IF(SOURCE!C24>=0,"F"))))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding multiple IF formulas into one cell](http://superuser.com/questions/897270/adding-multiple-if-formulas-into-one-cell)

Comment: In your first formula the `OR` contains two `AND`s that each have a single argument. `AND()` is designed to be used to combine two or more logical tests. So your first formula could be '=IF(OR(G14="No", G25="No"), "F")' which reads if either G14 is No or G25 is No then F with nothing specified about what to do when that isn't the case.

Comment: how would you add your formula to the one below it then?

Comment: @eirikdaude: The issue is pretty much the same as the suggested duplicate (which was also this OP's question).  However, the answers there gave a solution without adequately explaining the underlying principles so that they could be applied to this question.  So making this a duplicate won't help in this case.  I've attempted an answer that focuses on the principles, so the OP will be able to apply it to future problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous because it isn't clear, for example, what happens if C24 is >=90 and the first formula produces "F".  Since you put the first formula first, I'll assume that it takes precedence and the second formula comes into play only if the first formula is not "F".

The basic IF structure is:

```
IF(Condition, Then, Else)
```

You can nest multiple IFs, but the structure will be the same:

```
IF(Condition1, Then-1, IF(Condition2, Then-2, Else-2))
```

The second IF is the Else for the first IF.  In your second formula, you don't need the last IF, because the previous IFs leave it as the only remaining possibility, the "Else".  So the last term can be just "F".

Before getting to the solution, let me point out that in your first formula, the ANDs serve no purpose, since there is only one condition.  AND is used for where two or more conditions must all be true.  You only need the OR.

So basically, the structure you want is:

```
IF(1st Formula condition, then 1st formula result, else 2nd formula)
```

Which would look like this:

```
=IF(OR(G14="No",G25="No"),"F",second formula)
```

Or putting them together:

```
 IF(OR(G14="No",G25="No"),"F",IF(SOURCE!C24>=90,"A",IF(SOURCE!C24>=80,"B",IF(SOURCE!C24>=70,"C","F"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the logic of the formulas,
one can see that there are two different ways of getting an “F”:

- G14 or G25 = "No",  or,
- SOURCE!C24 is not ≥ 70.

I’m ignoring the fact that the formula in the question implies that the grade can be “F”
only if SOURCE!C24>=0.  I assume you put that there because the rule is that
numeric grades ≥ 0 and < 70 result in a letter grade of “F”. 
But, unless you actually want to handle numeric grades < 0
and give them a result other than “F”, you don’t need to do that test.

As a result of this common result, we can simplify fixer1234’s answer a little:

```
=IF(OR(G14="No",G25="No",Source!C24<70), "F", IF(Source!C24>=90, "A", IF(Source!C24>=80, "B", "C")))
```

<sup>This may look like it’s longer than fixer1234’s formula,
but that’s only because I added some spaces.</sup>

Now, you may look at the end of this formula and say
“No! Wait!  I don’t want to give a `C` to everybody
who doesn’t qualify for a `B` (numeric grade not ≥ 80);
a student has to have a grade ≥ 70 to get a `C`.” 
Well, take a look at the beginning of the formula. 
If a student’s grade is < 70, the `OR(…)` expression will be true,
the student will get a “F”, and the remainder of the formula
(`IF(Source!C24>=90, …`) will not be considered.